# Setting border colour with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple form in a html page with a single text box.I want that if I click the submit button with out any value in the text box then the border color of the text box shuld be red.Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ip').click(function(){
    var optionSelected = false;
    if($('#test').val().length == 0 ) {
      $("#test").css("border-color","red"); 
    }
  });
});
```

Here is the form

```
<form action="" id="form1">
Test:<input type="text" name="test" id="test">
<input type="submit" class ="ip">
</form>
```

But what is happening is that if I click the submit button without any value in the text box then the border color  of the text box is set to red momentarily.The red boder is not persisting in the text box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `return false` and `css("border","1px solid red")` instead of `css("border-color","red")`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ip').click(function(){
    var optionSelected = false;
    if($('#test').val().length == 0 ) {
      $("#test").css("border","1px solid red");//more efficient
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UtqcA/1/)

Answer (score 4):

add a return false, i guess the form does get submitted and reloads:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.ip').click(function(){
    var optionSelected = false;
    if($('#test').val().length == 0 ) {
      $("#test").css("border-color","red");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way to do it if you are using forms. Rather than using click event, I'm using submit event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#form1').submit(function(e) {
    var optionSelected = false;
    if($('#test').val().length != 0 ) {
      return true;
    } else { 
      $("#test").css("border-color","red");
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/UtqcA/